# Initializing a 2D Array from a 1D Array

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

I am creating a program to enroll students in classes for my project. What I am trying to do, is create a 2d array that will show the record like this:

### Course         Credits

English 101 -          3
Math 101   -          3
Course 101  -         3

I created a 1D array named courses - the array is filled in by the user. I also have a static int named credits that is always set to 3 - since all my courses for this are 3 credits. I know how to create that table in a different way, but the project calls for a 2d array somewhere in the program and I thought this would fulfill that requirement.

This is the code I have so far - I guess my issue is not knowing how to fill in those indexes.

```
public static void initializeStudentRecord(Student stu) {
    String[][] record = new String[stu.getNumCourses()][stu.getNumCourses()];
        for (int rows = 0; rows < record.length; rows++) {
            for (int cols = 0; cols < record[rows].length; cols++) {
                //record[rows][cols] = stu.getCourses();
        }
    stu.setStudentRecord(record);
}
```

I appreciate any help on this. I am a beginner and I apologize if I didn't post in this forum correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using a 2d array is the best approach for what you want to accomplish.
You should look into using a [HashMap](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashmap.asp) where you can have a key: value association.
I understand you are trying to use it because its a requirement for your project, but it won't work for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String[][] initializeStudentRecord(Student stu) {
    String[][] record = new String[stu.getNumCourses()][2];
        for (int rows = 0; rows < record.length; rows++) {
            record[rows][0] = stu.getCourses();
            record[rows][1] = "3";
        }
    stu.setStudentRecord(record);
}
```